# How to: Given a Hotel and checkin/Checkout time of visitors, find the minimum numbers of rooms required

Tags: algorithm

Say I get a list of unsorted tuples passed in as (checkin, checkout) and I need to return the minimum number of rooms I need in order to avoid conflict. 
So far I thought about:

```
 sort by checkout time
 room = 1 
 for each checkout time
    if there exists checkout time < checkin 
        room += 1
    end if 
 end for
 return room
```

sorting takes in nlogn + run through of the time (n) which equates to O(nlgn)
Can I do this better? I think I might have corner cases that I did not handle but I can't figure out any.

This was an interview question. Any help?

Comment: O(nlgn) is the best time. But I am doubt that your algorithm gives right result. Have you checked it on some examples? How does this line work: `if there exists checkout time < checkin ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is broken.  A correct one would be to make a list of events, then sort them by time first, then checkout before checkin.  Now we go as follows:

```
max_rooms = 0
rooms = 0
for each event
    if event.type == checkin
        rooms += 1
        if max_rooms < rooms
            max_rooms = rooms
        end if
    else
        rooms -= 1
    end if
end for
return max_rooms
```